# RecylerView with a fixed first row as header

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I would like to create a recycler view with a fixed first row, which should act as the header. Also ,how can I prevent it from scrolling with other row elements ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't put your fixed header in the `RecyclerView`. Wrap the `RecyclerView` in a `vertical` `LinearLayout`, with your fixed header above it.

Comment: Why is this a preferable approach?  One can easily set first items in a row of RecyclerView as the titles.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: By default, they will scroll with the rest of the items. I assume it's possible to rig things up to prevent those from scrolling, it would seem simpler in most cases to have them outside the `RecyclerView` in the first place. This is the approach used with `ListView` as well.

Comment: @CommonsWare But if the header cannot be scrolled, if it's too large, the user won't be able to see its whole content.

Comment: @androiddeveloper: So? The OP asked for a fixed header. If you do not want a fixed header in *your* project, don't use a fixed header.