# How to put RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedscrollview

With creation of [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) you can put scrolling view inside another scrolling view as long as those implement [NestedScrollingChild](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChild.html) and [NestedScrollingParent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingParent.html) correctly.

(This is not bad design pattern "Ian Lake (from Google) actually recommends putting a `RecyclerView` inside a nestedscrollview here: plus.google.com/u/0/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/9kZ3SsXdT2T")

I want to put [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) inside [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) and fortunately RecyclerView implements [NestedScrollingChild](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChild.html) so you can put it inside [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html).

```
public class RecyclerView extends ViewGroup implements ScrollingView, NestedScrollingChild
```

I have read these posts:

[How to use RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000081/how-to-use-recyclerview-inside-nestedscrollview)

[NestedScrolling with NestedScrollView, RecyclerView (Horizontal), inside a CoordinatorLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32448051/nestedscrolling-with-nestedscrollview-recyclerview-horizontal-inside-a-coord)

But the problem with most voted solution is, it calls all of the items of `RecyclerView` so for example if it is an endless RecyclerView and when the user reaches the end of the list you want to make a network request then with that solution the `RecyclerView` calls server repeatedly because it automatically reaches the last item of `RecyclerView`.

Anyway, how to set parameter so I can put `RecyclerView` inside `NestedScrollView`.(actually  I want to put a viewgroup like framelayout or relativelayout as a single childe of nestedscrollview and then I want to put recyclerview inside framelayout or relativelayout)

When I put `RecyclerView` inside `NestedScrollView` there is nothing to display.

---

In order to create a sample project you can use [cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) and change the `CheeseDetailActivity` to have a RecyclerView.

---

**Although the answer of BNK is not correct but BNK has tried a lot. So I award him the bounty. Still looking for nice solution....**

Comment: RecyclerView calls server repeatedly because it automatically reaches the last item of RecyclerView.. Are you sure about this ?

Comment: @Ramesh yes with suggested solution it calls the last visible item which is the last item of current data. it is not the real last visible item.

Comment: try this [link](http://androhub.com/android-toolbar-animation-using-design-support-library/).

Comment: @SurenderKumar thanks but read my question. that is not the answer i am looking for

Comment: If you want to put it in nested scrollview then you have to define the height of recycler view.

Comment: the height must be wrap_content.

Comment: Have you tried removing `FrameLayout` around `RecyclerView`? I assume that `NestedScrollView` checks the type of its direct child, but does not dive deeper than that. So, it has no way to discover that `RecyclerView` in fact implements Nested interface

Comment: @mmlooloo have you fixed the problem I am facing the scrolling is very laggy I have Imageview and `heterogenic layout` for row and also data is not populated properly. If I used only RecyclerView then it is working fine

Comment: @Kaushik no unfortunatly

Comment: Any news on this? I  am facing the same problem too... frustrating

Comment: @mmlooloo just checked latest recyclerview version; 25.0.0; the issue still exists, did you find any workarounds?

Comment: @EBLiS try andre719mv solution, it may work. I have not try it yet but some people said it is working.

Comment: @mmlooloo nope! non of the answers worked! I ended up with a recyclerview and a vertical linear layout manager, and replacing inner recyclerview with custom rows, for example four items in a row!!

Comment: @MohammadReza did using different  viewtypes in recyclerview solve the not recycling issue?

Answer (score 38):

The following is my new updated answer:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardview1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin">

                <LinearLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Info CardView1"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardview2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/cardview1"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin">

                <LinearLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Info CardView2"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/cardview2"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

In Activity:

```
        RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(true); // true: with header
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);            
        final MyLinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new MyLinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false, getScreenHeight(this));
        // final CustomLinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new CustomLinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);  
        // recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); // Disables scrolling for RecyclerView, however, CustomLinearLayoutManager used instead of MyLinearLayoutManager
```

I have also updated to [My GitHub's sample project](https://github.com/ngocchung/nestedscrollview)

Screenshot:

[image]

---

Comment: thanks but adding `android:fillViewport="true"` without adding framelayout dose not work. thanks again

Comment: Don't you want framelayout? Why not?

Comment: because adds depth in hierarchy views and also NestedScrollView is a vewgroup

Comment: I updated my answer, remove 2 lines `rv.setHasFixedSize(false);
        rv.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`, I check it works

Comment: actually your answer idea is the same as Simon, adding framelayout. if you can do without that then your answer will be the standard solution.

Comment: I have just replaced `FrameLayout` by `RelativeLayout`, it still works, ofcourse with `android:fillViewport="true"` :)

Comment: I know adding another viewgroup will work, you can add linearlayout and it will work. BUT it must work without any extra viewgroups. Because NestedScrollView itself is vewgroup. So standard solution must not add new viewgroups.

Comment: I will try it tomorrow :)

Comment: if you want the bounty try in 24+5 hrs.

Comment: Don't worry about the bounty, you can give it to Simon now. Actually, I have not read his answer yet, I only read the 2 links you provided. More important, I just want to have more knowledge about layouts :D. Now I on mobile so cannot test anymore, must wait until tomorrow :)

Comment: Regarding your comment "Because NestedScrollView itself is vewgroup. So standard solution must not add new viewgroups", how about standard ScrollView, inside it also another layout (Relative, Linear...)

Comment: ScrollView dose not implement NestedScrollingChild and NestedScrollingParent

Comment: So, you can try remove framelayout, then use setMinimumHeight() for recylerview to see if it work

Comment: thats ugly solution, the height must be wrap_content.

Comment: Pls look at my updated answer (full content of activity_detail.xml). I uploaded the customized project to https://github.com/ngocchung/cheesesquare-master

Comment: if I add recyclerview below of last cardView it dose not show. can you fix it? this is the main problem now.

Comment: Last cardView? Where is it? Is it your new requirement? In your question and your above comments, I only see your requirement is "recyclerview direct inside nestedscrollview without any framelayout, relativelayout..." and I have a working solution already

Comment: It is not a new requirement, I add recyclerView below the last card of cheessquer. if you answer `How to put RecycelerView inside NestedScrollView?` so it must work. dose not it?

Comment: No, I just cloned the cheesesquare project in your question and customized its CheeseDetailActivity, I don't care MainActivity

Comment: in CheeseDetailActivity there are some cardViews. it is in your `activity_detail_bk` layout. I have not changed anything and also have not added any new requirement.

Comment: I see your idea now, however, why do you want to keep those cardviews? You can move them into recyclerview instead

Comment: because in my main project I have to add a lot of widget and at the end I have to add recyclerview. adding those widget inside recyclerview and using view type really complex my design.

Comment: One more thing, if you keep those cardviews, you must put recyclerview inside LinearLayout because NestedScrollview can have only 1 direct child, but in your comments, you don't want any layout

Comment: yes I have to, but please make sure the recyclerview height is not fix, it must expand normally and as you scroll it fills the entire screen. not fix at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Pls take a look. Regariding to `not fix at the bottom of the page` I think you have to use code (looks like child scrollview inside parent scrollview)

Comment: "I think you have to use code (looks like child scrollview inside parent scrollview)" what do you mean?

Comment: I don't think a way using layout file for your requirement `not fix at the bottom of the page`, so I think you must use code more

Comment: I have just found a nicer solution, please go to my github to get updated code :)

Comment: Pls look at my updated answer, it works nicely, you can add recyclerview between cardviews too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94161/discussion-between-mmlooloo-and-bnk).

Comment: Sorry, I cannot chat now

Comment: I am sure that new updated code meets your requirements `make sure the recyclerview height is not fix, it must expand normally and as you scroll it fills the entire screen. not fix at the bottom of the page`, see you later :)

Comment: Calls the server? I don't undertand your idea? You get the data from the server in your project?

Comment: Read my question carefully

Comment: Hey! I don't know why you must and how did you make server request at the end of the list, however, read my following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32492011/how-to-load-datajson-into-recycler-view-using-volley/32492513#32492513, I often use that way to get data from server into recyclerview, I think it does not request over and over as you think

Comment: Your solution dose not satisfy pagination REST API.

Comment: If you're sure about "over and over" requests, post your code or your github's sample project and logcat information that displayed that thing

Comment: logcat the `findLastVisibleItemPosition()` method of LayoutManager . if your list has 50 items and just 5 items are visible that method should not return 50.

Comment: Log where? If inside activity, `Log.i("LOG",String.valueOf(myLinearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()));` output -1

Comment: inside recyclerView.addOnScrollListener

Comment: I have tried, it is 0 first, then when scrolling, addOnScrollListener not called anymore. If add it inside setOnScrollChangeListener of nestedScrollView, it always 0 too

Comment: But mine is called, just google it, I think you have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Wrong called, now right method: `11-04 15:43:26.216 3090-3090/com.support.android.designlibdemo I/visibleItemCount: 150
11-04 15:43:26.216 3090-3090/com.support.android.designlibdemo I/totalItemCount: 150
11-04 15:43:26.216 3090-3090/com.support.android.designlibdemo I/pastVisiblesItems: 149`

Comment: pastVisiblesItems is String.valueOf(layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()). Must log inside `setOnScrollChangeListener` of ScrollView

Comment: So now I think you touch the problem:-) now If you can find a solution.

Comment: visibleItemCount: 150 == totalItemCount: 150

Comment: `visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
                totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
                pastVisiblesItems = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();`

Comment: Sorry, actually, I still cannot understand your idea `over and over request`. If you don't mind, please post your code or your github sample project that having this issue so that I can check more

Comment: Sorry, I cannot chat. What a pity my answer cannot work completely for all your requirements. Actually I have not ever tried pagination Rest API before, however, with your current question, I have more knowlegde about the new layouts of Android, thanks anyway, see you later :)

Comment: What is the value of `mVisibleThreshold`? Do you mean `End has been reached` always reached?

Comment: and also I wonder why you can add a lot of comment but can not chat on stackoverflow. I think you misunderstand the chat on this site. just press the link it is as if you are commenting

Comment: if you press the link ` automatically move this discussion to chat?` when you are going to add new comment we can chat by typing like here.

Comment: when you press `add comments` and the dialog is opened to write there is a link above that dialog. try it

Comment: I have posted in chat windows, don't you see it?

Comment: Hi! Please go to my new sample project https://github.com/ngocchung/NestedScrollView, I use a little trick with screenheight. Please take a look, although it is not 100% as nice as you want, however, the last item will not be reached automatically. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you, right now I have to fix some other part of my main project, when I reach that UI I will surely try your new sample. I have understand your trick, it seems work nicely. again thanks.

Comment: Hello! Long time no see :) Have you reached that UI and have you tried my sample yet?

Comment: No I finally used recyclerview with multi view type holder.

Comment: Uhm, sound better, then you don't need nestedscrollview anymore, right?

Comment: Suppose all I want to add is a header to the RecyclerView (jst as done for ListeView). Is it possible by using a NestedScrollView ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: do you mean like this one http://robusttechhouse.com/tutorial-how-to-add-header-to-recyclerview-in-android/ ?

Comment: @BNK Yes, but without changing the adapter. For the adapter solution, I've already found how to do it, and wrote about it, here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33746292/878126 . The adapter solution also has a disadvantage that the adapter needs to manage the header, so I can't just call "setVisibility" on the header view (because it leaves an empty, unused space for some reason).

Comment: @androiddeveloper: IMO, if recyclerview is the only one inside nestedscrollview, why don't we put it inside linearlayout instead, don't need nestedscrollview anymore. Then, use another textview/cardview as the header. **Commonware** has had the same idea at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873176/recylerview-with-a-fixed-first-row-as-header, pls take a look.

Comment: @BNK Well, if the LinearLayout is the parent, how would the header be scrolled, so that if it's too large, the user could scroll and show the rest of the header ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper The header is often sticky/fixed postion, I think :)

Comment: @BNK wouldn't it be weird to have a header that takes space, so that your recyclerView take less space? I guess it depends on the requirements...

Comment: @androiddeveloper: so, you can try replacing header view by an empty view instead of setVisibility(View.GONE)

Comment: @BNK I don't think it will work.I've decided to add a boolean in the adapter to show/hide the header, instead, and it worked.

Comment: @androiddeveloper I just updated my sample project at GitHub that also uses boolean variable, please take a look if it is the same as yours https://github.com/ngocchung/NestedScrollView

Comment: @BNK Wait, so you succeeded using a nestedScrollView , in order to have a header for the recyclerView ? If so, please put your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33729642/878126

Comment: @androiddeveloper: you can download my sample code, I have read your question before, however I don't understand much, and haven't ever tried `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` so cannot post an answer :)

Comment: @BNK Using StaggeredGridLayoutManager  was just for checking out if it's a possible solution, but then I've found I can use spanning on the GridLayoutManager, and updated the question. The sample works, but it allows me to scroll on the recyclerView without having the header being scrolled together with it. Probably because of the NestedScrollView

Comment: @androiddeveloper: you can try scrolling again, the header scrolled, as my screenshot in GitHub

Comment: @BNK It still allows to scroll the recyclerView yet the header doesn't get scrolled. Try to scroll to the top, and then start touching the recyclerView and scroll there. The header gets fixed in its location, while the recyclerView gets scrolled.

Comment: @androiddeveloper: pls see the screenshots https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2HGUM4c0YwpR3VXakVNSDc0Y1E/view?usp=sharing and https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2HGUM4c0YwpUzFWQUxKcV9UR0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @BNK As I wrote, it doesn't work well. Here's a video : https://files.fm/g/ndlbwvk#aa/device-2015-11-20-012911.mp4

Comment: @androiddeveloper if you don't want the RV to be scrolled inside NSV as in the video,simply call recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);, however, then RV will not display all child items when using `MyLinearLayoutManager`, `CustomLinearLayoutManager` should be used instead

Comment: @BNK So a NestedScrollView is not a good solution as I thought. OK.

Comment: hi....great solution....but i want to use grid layout of recyclerview...how can i?

Comment: @HRaval sorry, I have not ever tried it before, IMO, you can read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744788/changing-number-of-columns-in-recyclerview-gridlayout and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566954/recyclerview-gridlayoutmanager-set-square-dimensions or search more in S.O

Comment: Hi guys! Super interesting conversation! I was checking out @BNK's project (https://github.com/ngocchung/NestedScrollView) and started playing with it a little bit, since I needed to do something similar. I have one question though, when the content ABOVE the recyclerview (CardViews) fit in the screen without the need of scrolling down, the content gets scrolled down automatically to the start of the Recyclerview. You can test this by removing or commenting one of the CardViews at the top of `content_main.xml`. Is there a workaround for this behaviour? Ideally, I do not want this autoscroll

Comment: @acrespo thanks for your comment. For your issue, please add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in the first `RelativeLayout` under the `NestedScrollView`

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your quick reply @BNK! That totally did it.

Comment: @BNK Scrolling is working, but even in your sample it stucks when user start scrolling from recyclerView. So in default case if user made a long swipe from bottom, whole view would scrolled to down maximally, but if we had nested scrollView over recycler view it would scrolled in a few pixels and stuck. So i still don't have a solution except old one via headers in RV adapter

Comment: if i put recycleview inside NestedScrollView it calling bindviewholder for all row

Comment: @andro thanks for your comment, I have seen that too

Comment: @andro I have started a bounty on your question, hope that someone helps you find a working solution

Comment: Thanks for "android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" !

Comment: as mentioned, all the rows are being bound (so if i have 100 items, bindViewholder is called 100 times) since the nestedscrollview expands to fill the height of RV (with all item loaded), no matter if match or wrap content. That's the logic of NestedScrollView, but is there still no workaround for that?

Answer (score 26):

Here is solution to call server only when you are realy need to load more data. In this way you can put your endless RecyclerView and many other views inside NestedScrollView. For me it is working well.

**1.** Create **EndlessParentScrollListener** class to handle scroll events from NestedSrollView.

```
public abstract class EndlessParentScrollListener implements NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener {
        // The current offset index of data you have loaded
        private int currentPage = 0;
        // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
        private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;
        // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
        private boolean loading = true;
        // Sets the starting page index
        private int startingPageIndex = 0;
        // The minimum amount of pixels to have below your current scroll position
        // before loading more.
        private int visibleThresholdDistance = 300;

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

        public EndlessParentScrollListener(RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager) {
            this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView scrollView, int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy) {
            // We take the last son in the scrollview
            View view = scrollView.getChildAt(scrollView.getChildCount() - 1);
            int distanceToEnd = (view.getBottom() - (scrollView.getHeight() + scrollView.getScrollY()));

            int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            // If the total item count is zero and the previous isn't, assume the
            // list is invalidated and should be reset back to initial state
            if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {
                this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
                this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
                if (totalItemCount == 0) {
                    this.loading = true;
                }
            }

            // If it’s still loading, we check to see if the dataset count has
            // changed, if so we conclude it has finished loading and update the current page
            // number and total item count.
            if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
                loading = false;
                previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            }

            // If it isn’t currently loading, we check to see if we have breached
            // the visibleThreshold and need to reload more data.
            // If we do need to reload some more data, we execute onLoadMore to fetch the data.
            // threshold should reflect how many total columns there are too
            if (!loading && distanceToEnd <= visibleThresholdDistance) {
                currentPage++;
                onLoadMore(currentPage, totalItemCount);
                loading = true;
            }
        }

        // Defines the process for actually loading more data based on page
        public abstract void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount);
    }
```

**2.** Set listener

```
private void initRecycler() {  
        //TODO init recycler adapter here

        recycler.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);          
        LinearLayoutManager _layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recycler.setLayoutManager(_layoutManager);
        NestedScrollView scrollView = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new EndlessParentScrollListener(_layoutManager) {
                @Override
                public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {                     
                    if (loadedItemCount < serverItemsCount)
                        customLoadMoreDataFromApi();
                }
            });
        customLoadMoreDataFromApi();
    }
```

Short xml if someone find it usefull:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
            ...
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
                android:scrollbars="vertical">

                <!-- some views goes here-->

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerFeed"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

                <!-- and possibly here-->

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: @mmlooloo you should submit this answer

Comment: is all children of the RecyclerView still visible due to being a child of NestedScrollView and would cause OutOfMemoryException like this? or it is safe?

Comment: Hello ! By using your advice, I've almost reach to my goals !
But I have still facing some trivial(?) problem.

When I call [loadMore], device stop for a moment. During the instance, i can't scolling or any other touching. Of course it is just really really temporary but it is on my mind continuously.

Could you give me any recommend~?

Comment: Inside of loadMore you need to load your data in Asynchronous Background Thread. Not in UI thread. This is what you can start from:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/

Comment: Thank you, you saved me. I wish I could up vote this many times

Comment: @dgngulcan, may be they are visible. But I used this approach in production many times and never got OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: Work Like Charm. Nice approach to do this on ScrollView and NestedScrollView.

Comment: @andre719mv Your solution was working . but app heap size was increasing when i load more data then it caused to Out Of Memory error.

Answer (score 10):

So put RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView directly will unfortunately display nothing. However, there is a way to put the recyclerview inside the NestedScrollView indirectly - just use a frameLayout as the third party to hold your recyclerview.

This is the framelayout which holds the nested recyclerview in your **activity** class:

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".ExampleFragment"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            >
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
   </FrameLayout>
```

Put your fragment into the **framelayout** (code sits within the **activity** class):

```
 ExampleFragment exampleFragment = new ExampleFragment();

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.container, exampleFragment);
    ft.commit();
```

In your **exampleFragment**, you can then put your recyclerview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/post_container"
        android:background="#E0E0E0">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the **fragment** code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            llLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment_layout, container, false);
                    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) llLayout.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
```

The following is the **CheeseSquare** XML layout you should have:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".ExampleFragment"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            >
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
   </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_discuss"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: not working, I have posted the detail layout of cheesesquare, which I put the recyclerview inside the framelayout. check edited question

Comment: But my answer does not put the recyclerview into the framelayout. It has an outer framelayout with an embedded inner nestedscrollview. We are loading the fragment into the framelayout and the fragment is the one that contains the recyclerview.

Comment: I can not understand your answer. can you edit the activity detail layout. just clone the cheesesquare and put the recyclerview of CheeseListFragment into CheeseDetailActivity.

Comment: I have changed your cheesesquare xml layout to include the layout that it should include.

Comment: thank you so much! the bounty will be awarded automatically as I have accepted.

Comment: in cheesesquare it works, but for main project I do not know so far.

Comment: I think the answer of BNK is better and there is no need for adding another viewgroup.

Comment: I don't think my solution is more complex then BNK - we are both adding more depth into your layout hierarchy. He does it by enclosing a recyclerview inside a linearlayout inside a nestedscrollview. I'm doing it by enclosing a nestedscrollview into a framelayout and then inflating the fragment into the framelayout. In my example, my xml code is actually simplier and easier to maintain.

Comment: @Simon: recylcerview can be directly inside nestedscrollview, however, as in my 1st updated answer, it should be the only child of nestedscrollview. If having many other views, need to set fixed length for recyclerview, but if too many views or views have big height, recyclerview does not display.

Comment: how to handling for load more android with collapsing toolbar with nestedscroll of recycelrview android please help

Answer (score 0):

I have wasted at least a week behind this and the only solution that works is to remove the `nestedscrollview`. I know that is not the answer to this particular question of adding `recyclerview` inside `nestedscrollview`, but to make the recyclerview to actually **recycle the view**, you **HAVE TO REMOVE** the `nestedscrollview`. If you happen to have multiple `view` inside instead of just the `recyclerview`, You have to add them as items of the `recyclerview` by setting different viewholders, and then adding

`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

to the recyclerview or the parent of `recyclerview`(the parent cannot have any other view other than Recyclerview for this to work).

In my case, the requirement was as follows:

```
  <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <!-- Scrollable view here -->

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            ....   >

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                ....>

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    ....>

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_header_view"
                        .... />
                </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

                <include layout="@layout/widget_header" />
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            ....>
            <LinearLayout orientation="vertical" ....>
                <View .../>  <!-- I needed to have these two views along with recyclerview and i wanted them to do nestedscroll along with recyclerview -->
                <View .../>
                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                .... />
        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I needed to have two views before `recyclerview` and I wanted them to do nestedscroll along with `recyclerview`. The only thing that worked was by removing these to views and adding them as the first two items of `recyclerview`, and then adding

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

to the `swipetorefresh` layout

Hope this helps someone. I will add more info If required.