# Recycleview not scroll in nested scrollview android

Tags: android, android-scrollview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/todoDetailsCoordinatorLayout"
    android:background="@color/windowBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/todoEditMainLl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/windowBackground"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/todoDetailsAppBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/todoDetailsToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:contentInsetStart="10dp"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/todoDetailsBottomLl"
            android:layout_below="@+id/todoDetailsAppBar"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/todoDetailsScrollView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/todoEditTopLl"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/windowBackground"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="visible">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/eight_dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_single_line_height"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="@dimen/avatar_icon_touch_area_size"
                                    android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_icon_touch_area_size"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:orientation="vertical">

                                    <ImageView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:src="@drawable/todo_user"
                                        android:visibility="visible" />
                                </LinearLayout>

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_item_content_left_padding"
                                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:orientation="vertical">

                                    <com.strait.solvenow.Utilities.WithoutPrimaryTextView
                                        android:id="@+id/EditTodoTxtAssignToName"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:singleLine="true"
                                        android:text="" />

                                    <com.strait.solvenow.Utilities.WithoutSecondaryTextView
                                        android:id="@+id/EditTodoTxtAssignByName"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:singleLine="true"
                                        android:text=""

                                        />
                                </LinearLayout>
                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/todo_details_height"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="@dimen/avatar_icon_touch_area_size"
                                    android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_icon_touch_area_size"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:orientation="vertical">

                                    <ImageView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                        android:src="@drawable/todo_due_date" />
                                </LinearLayout>

                                <com.strait.solvenow.Utilities.WithoutPrimaryTextView
                                    android:id="@+id/EditToDoTxtDueDate"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_item_content_left_padding"
                                    android:background="@null"
                                    android:gravity="left|center"
                                    android:text="@string/Due_Date" />

                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/todo_details_height"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="@dimen/avatar_icon_touch_area_size"
                                    android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_icon_touch_area_size"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:orientation="vertical">

                                    <ImageView
                                        android:id="@+id/todoDetailsImgStatus"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:src="@drawable/user_place_holder" />
                                </LinearLayout>

                                <com.strait.solvenow.Utilities.WithoutPrimaryTextView
                                    android:id="@+id/EditToDoTxtStatus"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_item_content_left_padding"
                                    android:background="@null"
                                    android:gravity="left|center"
                                    android:text="@string/Status" />

                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/todo_details_height"
                                android:gravity="center|left"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="@dimen/avatar_icon_touch_area_size"
                                    android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_icon_touch_area_size"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:orientation="vertical">

                                    <ImageView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:src="@drawable/todo_notification" />
                                </LinearLayout>

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_item_content_left_padding"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                                    <com.strait.solvenow.Utilities.WithoutPrimaryTextView
                                        android:id="@+id/todoDetailsTxtNotify"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                        android:gravity="center"
                                        android:text="@string/Notifications" />


                                    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                                        android:id="@+id/todoEditTglNotification"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/ten_dp"
                                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/todoDetailsTxtNotify"
                                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                        android:button="@null"
                                        android:checked="false"
                                        android:text=""
                                        android:textColor="@color/textColorWithoutPrimary"
                                        android:textOff=""
                                        android:textOn="" />

                                </LinearLayout>

                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/todo_details_height"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="@dimen/avatar_icon_touch_area_size"
                                    android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_icon_touch_area_size"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:orientation="vertical">

                                    <ImageView
                                        android:id="@+id/todoEditImgAttachment"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:src="@drawable/todo_new_attach" />
                                </LinearLayout>

                                <com.strait.solvenow.Utilities.WithoutPrimaryTextView
                                    android:id="@+id/chatEditTxtAttachment"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_item_content_left_padding"
                                    android:gravity="center|left"
                                    android:text="@string/Attachment" />

                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/todo_details_height"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_item_content_left_padding"
                                android:gravity="center|left"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <com.strait.solvenow.Utilities.WithoutPrimaryTextView
                                    android:id="@+id/chatEditTxtReminder"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/todoEditImgAttachment"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:gravity="center|left"
                                    android:text="@string/Reminder"
                                    android:visibility="visible" />

                                <com.strait.solvenow.Utilities.WithoutPrimaryTextView
                                    android:id="@+id/chatEditTxtForward"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/todoEditImgAttachment"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:gravity="center|left"
                                    android:text="@string/Forward" />

                                <com.strait.solvenow.Utilities.WithoutPrimaryTextView
                                    android:id="@+id/chatEditTxtRejected"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/todoEditImgAttachment"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:gravity="center|left"
                                    android:text="@string/Reject" />
                            </LinearLayout>


                        </LinearLayout>
                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                    <!--    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                            android:id="@+id/todoSwipeRefresh"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_above="@+id/chatWindowBottomRl">
    -->
                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/todoRv"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/five_dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
                        android:visibility="visible"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                    <!--</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>-->
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/todoDetailsBottomLl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/todoChatBottomVerticalLine"
                layout="@layout/divider_view_line"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/windowBackground"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:visibility="visible">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/todoChatImgAttachment"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/avatar_icon_touch_area_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_icon_touch_area_size"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:padding="@dimen/icon_padding"
                    android:src="@drawable/chat_attachment"
                    android:visibility="visible" />


                <com.strait.solvenow.Utilities.WithoutEditTextView
                    android:id="@+id/todoChatEdtTextMsg"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five_dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/todoChatImgSend"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/todoChatImgAttachment"
                    android:background="@drawable/chat_window_text_msg_bg"
                    android:hint=""
                    android:maxLines="4"
                    android:minHeight="35dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/ten_dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/todoChatImgSend"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/avatar_icon_touch_area_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_icon_touch_area_size"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="@dimen/icon_padding"
                    android:src="@drawable/send"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have using recycle view inside nested Scroll view but Recycle view not scroll down in nested scroll view.recycle view scroll down when keyboard open and new item add in recycle view.here is above my code.

Comment: put some code that you have tried

Comment: Simple. Get rid of the ScrollView. RecyclerView handles your scrolling needs.

Comment: I have put my code ....please check my code what is problem .

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is bad layout technique you have implement

According to **android standard** there are no more than two Scrolling views inside one layout

Make a proper layout for same

Answer (score 0):

You should disable scrolling of recyclerview :

> ```
>  recycler.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
> ```

You should also set height of recyclerview to wrap_content

> android:layout_height="wrap_content"

[How to put RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330388/how-to-put-recyclerview-inside-nestedscrollview)

Comment: please check my xml file