# How to use RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have this layout:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <--There is some layouts here-->
            <RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

It works well. I can scroll `RecyclerView` smoothly without scrolling parent view.

Now I have to put the `RecyclerView` inside a `FrameLayout` like this:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
 <--There is some layouts here-->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/review_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/empty_view"
                layout="@layout/review_empty_view"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Now I cannot scroll the `RecyclerView` smoothly.
All I want is: scroll `RecyclerView` smoothly without scrolling parent view. What should I do?

**EDIT**: Here is my review_empty layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/shopping_review_empty" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/shopping_no_review_message" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: add this line recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

Comment: @Akash I added. It helps to scroll the `RecyclerView` smoothly. But it scrolls my parent view too. I don't want the parent view to be scrolled

Comment: What you want to achieve using FrameLayout?

Comment: I want to add a new view called "empty view" on top of `RecyclerView`. So I added both of them to a `FrameLayout`

Comment: @TOP can you explain me for what purpose u use FrameLayout?

Comment: @ND1010_ I want to add a new view called "empty view" on top of `RecyclerView`. So I added both of them to a FrameLayout

Comment: @TOP  did you mean by  like any TextView or View?

Comment: @ND1010_ You can see my second layout above. I included a "empty_view". It will be shown on top of `RecyclerView` in case there is no data

Comment: @TOP are load images in shopping_review_empty ImageView ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146247/discussion-between-nd1010-and-top).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000081/how-to-use-recyclerview-inside-nestedscrollview)

Answer (score 4):

just enable nestedscrolling that will enable smooth scrollview.

```
RecyclerView v = (RecyclerView) findViewById(...);
v.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: It helps to scroll the RecyclerView smoothly. But it scrolls other views too. I don't want other views to be scrolled while I scroll only `RecyclerView`

Comment: android:fillViewport="true"              add this to your nestedschroll

Comment: I added but it still the same

Answer (score 2):

Use this in your recyclerView

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/review_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <ScrollView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1" >
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        <include
            android:id="@+id/empty_view"
            layout="@layout/review_empty_view"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Try this...

Answer (score 1):

I am suggesting you to do like this. When you get Empty Data then just set Recycler View Visibility as Gone and set Empty View Visibility as Visible.

Here is Code :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:background="@color/bg"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_30dp">

                <include layout="@layout/image_loading_progress" />

                <com.thenakedconvos.stories.utils.CircularImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivProfile"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/scale_90dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/scale_90dp"
                    android:transitionName="@string/transition_image" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <com.thenakedconvos.stories.widget.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvUserName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_15dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:transitionName="@string/transition_text"
                app:typeface="gotham_medium" />

            <com.thenakedconvos.stories.widget.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvHoots"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:typeface="gotham_book" />

            <com.vanniktech.emoji.EmojiTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSmiley"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_10dp"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                app:emojiSize="25sp" />

            <com.thenakedconvos.stories.widget.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvAddFriend"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/red_rect_box"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/scale_12dp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/scale_12dp"
                android:text="Add"
                android:textColor="@color/red"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:theme="@style/AppTheme">

            <com.thenakedconvos.stories.widget.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:typeface="bariol_bold" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_15dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/scale_16dp">

            <com.thenakedconvos.stories.widget.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvUserStory"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Amy N. Johnson's Stories"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                app:typeface="bariol_bold" />

            <com.thenakedconvos.stories.widget.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTotalStories"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_5dp"
                android:text="110 Stories"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                app:typeface="bariol_bold" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_10dp"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/scale_10dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: I have to use `NestedScrollView`. Because in Landscape screen, there is not enough space for the `RecyclerView`. There are some other layout before `RecyclerView` (I do not show them in above code). So I need the `NestedScrollView` to allow users to scroll screen to see full `RecyclerView`

Comment: Yes you can do this using NestedScrollView too.Just Add this line if you are using NestedScrollView. recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

Comment: I added. It helps to scroll the `RecyclerView` smoothly. But it scrolls my parent view too. I don't want to scroll the parent view while scrolling `RecyclerView`

Comment: No. Parent view means the whole `LinearLayout` inside the `NestedScrollView`. It is the view with id = "content" in above layout

Comment: Inside any View in NestedScroll is Scrolling. have you put any Image to your Linear Layout?

Comment: Please see my updated questions. I added some comments in the layout code. You can see: there are some layouts before the `FrameLayout`

Comment: so you don't want that commented layout will be scroll?

Comment: Yes. I only want to scroll my `RecyclerView` smoothly without scrolling other views.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146240/discussion-between-akash-and-top).

Answer (score 1):

That may be a chance you loading images(static)  in to ImageView can be slow your recyclerView.

Or Big size of image.

Try to run application on mobile have good size of RAM

Answer (score 0):

Add fillViewport is true in NestedScrollView in xml file as below:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none">
```

And In your activity setNested scrolling false as below code

```
recycler_view.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: When I scroll the RecyclerView, I don't want other views to be scrolled too. Your code help me to scroll RecyclerView smoothly. But it scrolls whole view too

Comment: Please provide code for "review_empty_view", so that I can further help

Comment: See my updated question. I added the "review_empty_view"

Comment: Please set your recyclerView height to 100 or 200dp, let me know if it works for you

Comment: Do not do this. It will prevent views from being recycled.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your "not scrollable"  layout outside the nested scroll view

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is use below line in your activity class:

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recycler_view, false);
```

its compatible for lower versions also. and if you want to give compatible to API >21 only then use;

```
  recycler_view.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```